# Lotto breaker program whats the equation

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsset, equation-solving

I was curious as to what it would take to mathematically  solve lotto. Just For Fun.

So I decided to find out exactly how many tickets I would need to buy, if I wanted to win the next Week's Lotto.

MY GOAL IS TO CREATE EVERY SINGLE TICKET POSSIBLE

I  wrote  a small program, which can generate every possible  Lotto Ticket. Works fine, but  it has two problems I can't figure out how to solve:

1. Every time i work with larger values or large ranges Eg 6*49 the
   App FREEZES for hours calculating, in the end  the App crashes. But
   if I try to calculate small values and ranges eg all possible 3*5
   LOTTO tickets THE PROGRAM Works fine No Crash (3*5== means ....
   Amount of numbers*The Biggest Number)
2. Problem two is: I do not know how to make the program  stop. I
   have some End-results but I cannot figure out the equation to get
   to the end results or make the (WHILE LOOP STOP) program stop
   working. At the moment I just  set it so that if it makes a million
   duplicate tickets. There are no more possible tickets to
   make, Exit Now.

The results i get from the experiment are :

```
3*3=1                   

3*4=4 

3*5=10 ( ie 10 maximum possible tickets)

3*6=20

3*7=35

3*8=56
```

Or If i work With 4s

```
4*4=1

4*5=5

4*6=15

4*7=35

4*8=70
```

or if i use 6s

```
6*6=1

6*7=7

6*8=28

6*9=84
```

There is website that can easily calculate it but i have no idea what the equation is:

http://www.lotterynumberspro.com/lottery-odds-calculator.php

My code so far

```objectivec
 //******************************Start Values*******************************************************************************

    NSMutableArray*starArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:Rangesize];
    NSMutableSet *aSet;
    int x;
    for (x=1; x<=Rangesize; x++) {[starArray addObject:@(x)] ;}

    NSMutableArray*allStartValues=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:starArray];

    NSLog(@"First ticket = %@",[allStartValues componentsJoinedByString:@"_"]);


    //***************************Master Array with one object*****************
    NSMutableArray*masterArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:allStartValues, nil];

    NSLog(@"The masterArray initialized  = %@",[masterArray componentsJoinedByString:@"_"]);





    //****************************************Search Master for instances of new ticket*************
    int count=0;
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];

    while ([masterArray containsObject:allStartValues]&& count<=100000) {


        NSMutableSet *aSet2=[[NSMutableSet alloc]initWithCapacity:Rangesize];

        while(([aSet2 count]!=Rangesize))
        {
            int Randnum = (arc4random() % BnSize)+1;
            [aSet2 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Randnum]];
        }

        NSArray *arrayOfUniqueRandomNumbers = [aSet2 allObjects];
        NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: YES];
        NSArray*new=[arrayOfUniqueRandomNumbers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];





        for(NSArray*EachElement in masterArray)
        {

            if ([masterArray containsObject:new]) {

                count++;
                break;
            }

            else {
 NSLog(@"ticket %@  Pass to add to Master",[new componentsJoinedByString:@"_"]);
                [masterArray addObject:new];
              //  NSLog(@"The masterArray updated  = %@",[masterArray componentsJoinedByString:@"_"]);
                break;
            }
        }       
    }

    int c=1;
    for (NSArray*element in masterArray) {

        [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ticket (%i) is >> %@  \n",c ,[element componentsJoinedByString:@"_"]]];          

        _Scroll.text=string;
        c++;
        //NSLog(@"array size = %i",[masterArray count]);

    }
    }

@end
```

ANYONE KNOW HOW TO MAKE THIS PROGRAM BETTER??

Comment: There's a lot of ways to make something 'better'. Can you be more specific?

Comment: There's no equation, and the number of tickets you need to buy to be certain of winning is the same as the number of possible combinations. The exact number depends on the particular lottery, but it's likely to be in the hundreds of millions. That takes a fair amount of time and space to compute.

Comment: The program keeps freezing wen i use large numbers...my best guess is its a memory problem...My Pc is only  2gb RAM and every time i run the program My memory drops down to 12mb then the App crashes...small numbers work no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to compute the number of ways to
choose `k` different items out of `n`. That number is given by the ["Binomial coefficient"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) `C(n, k)`

For example,
the number of possibilities to choose 4 different numbers out of 1, ..., 7 is
 `C(7, 4) = 35`.

The binomial coefficient can be computed without actually creating all possible combinations as

```
          n  * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * (n-k+1)
C(n, k) = ----------------------------------
          1  *   2   *   3   * ... *    k
```

**ADDED:** *(In response to your comment)* It is not necessary to compute factorials in
order to compute `C(n, k)`. In other words, one would normally *not* use the formula
`C(n, k) = n! / (k! * (n-k)!)` because the factorials get quite large.

Instead you use the above expression in the form

```
          n    (n-1)   (n-2)          (n-k+1)
C(n, k) = -  * ----- * -----  * ... * -------
          1      2       3               k
```

A simple implementation could look like this:

```
long long int choose(int n, int k)
{
    if (k < 0 || k > n)
        return 0;

    long long int result = 1;
    // Use the fact that C(n, k) == C(n, n-k) to reduce k:
    if (k > n - k)
        k = n - k;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        result = (result * (n+1-i)) / i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Of course this can also overflow if the numbers get too large. But (since `long long int` has at least 64 bit) this is sufficient to compute all binomial coefficients up to `n = 60`.

Comment: This is quite correct in that it will yield the _number_ of tickets. I thought the OP was asking for an equation for the tickets themselves.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: The question is not clear without ambiguity, but I decided to offer this solution because OP said *"... find out exactly how many tickets I would need to buy"*. That is also what the linked-to "Lottery Calculator" computes. You are of course right that actually creating all the combinations would take a lot of time. - So I am waiting for some feedback from the OP to see if that is what he needed!

Comment: Agreed, this does answer that part.

Comment: Hey  Martin i just finished building the  function for the equation ...it works fine but  i cannot calculate  factorials for numbers greater than 20 or 21...Factorials are extremely large numbers 20plus digits....i tried  long int   doesnt work.....i tried long-long int  not working either..im not sure what to do

Comment: @BrianBeaven: I have added more information and sample code.

Comment: @BrianBeaven: You are welcome! - (Please note that you can "accept" helpful answers by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved, and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer.)

Comment: Hey Martin i just  tried  code....:) thanks works like a charm...That solved the Stop part of the program...and 60 should be fine by the way, most lotto's range  (40-53). After  i tested extreme values ....i  ran  instruments Time profiler..I tried a 6*40 problem....total  maximum tickets == 3,900,000..but My Pc takes 4 minutes to generates 20,000 tickets...i would need A LOT! of time just to print 4 million tickets ...:( bummer

Comment: @BrianBeaven: Do you need only the *number* of tickets or do you actually want to *generate* all tickets?

Comment: Generate All Possible tickets

Comment: @BrianBeaven: Did you google for "generate all combinations"? I think there are better algorithms than yours.